# Prolog: Pass User-Input as Parameters

Tags: io, prolog

I am new to Prolog and therefore need help with the following task.

I have the programm:

```
do(save) :- save_bal(bad).
do(act) :- save_bal(good), inc(good).
do(comb) :- save_bal(good), inc(bad).
save_bal(good) :- savMoney(X), depPeople(Y), Min is Y * 1000, X >= Min.
save_bal(bad) :- not(save_bal(good)).
inc(good) :- earn(Z), depPeople(Y), MinE is 3000 + Y * 400, Z >= MinE.
inc(bad) :- not(inc(good)).
savMoney(30000).
earn(60000).
depPeople(4).
```

My task is to rewrite this programm, so the numbers 30000, 60000 and 4 is set by a user input. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
:- read(A), savMoney(A).
:- read(B), earn(B).
:- read(C), depPeople(C).
```

But that won't work.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which prolog interpreter are you using? The `:-` is for directives. Write a predicate to read the user input, and use `assert` to assert the facts in the prolog "database".

Comment: Hello mbratch

I am using SWI-Prolog. Can you make an example with your suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

cece

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolog is an [homoiconic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity), then the first step you should take is to *declare* which predicate are data, and which are (just to say) logic constraints on the data.

Then, add near top of file (just a stylistic hint) the declarations

```
:- dynamic(savMoney/1).
:- dynamic(earn/1).
:- dynamic(depPeople/1).
```

then you can add a service predicate, say user_update_store/1, like

```
user_update_store(Entry) :-
  AccessValueCurr =.. [Entry, ValueCurr],
  (retract(AccessValueCurr) -> true ; ValueCurr = 0),
  format('enter value for ~s (current is ~w):', [Entry, ValueCurr]),
  read(NewValue),
  % validate it's a number etc...
  StoreNewValue =.. [Entry, NewValue],
  assertz(StoreNewValue).
```

now you can start your user interface:

```
?- maplist(user_udpdate_store, [savMoney,earn,depPeople]).
```

this code should work for every (ISO compliant) Prolog. Note: I didn't tested it...

HTH

Answer (score 2):

CapelliC provided an excellent (better) answer while I was busy typing away at this monstrosity. In fact, I didn't end up addressing the question in your title, because you were passing parameters just fine. Instead I wrote about `assertz/1` and `retract/1`. However, I taught myself a fair amount while composing it and you might also find it informative.

In your example code, we have 3 facts declared with the predicates `savMoney/1`, `earn/1`, `depPeople/1'. We then have a number of rules that determine values based on these facts. A rule is of the form` :- .`, and which I sometimes read to myself as "<head> is true if <body> is true". We can think of a fact as a rule of the form` :- true`, e.g.,`savMoney(30000) :- true.`, which we might read as "30000 is savMoney if true is true", and true is true or we're all screwed. (BTW, is 'savMoney' short for saved money?)

A directive is of the form `:- <body>.`. It is like a rule that must be tested in order for the program (or world) to be true (this is more evocative than accurate, because, as you've seen, when a directive fails the whole program-world is not false, we just get a warning). When we consult a prolog file, we add new *rules* and *facts* to our program-world, and these can even be impossible nonsense statements like `a :- \+ a.` "a is true if not-a is true"<sup>1</sup>. That contradiction will cause cause a stack overflow if you query `?- a.`, but the program will load just fine. However, *directives* have to be evaluated and settled while the program loads in the order they are encountered:

This program will throw a stack overflow error when the interpreter consults it.

```
a :- \+ a.
:- a.
```

This program will throw an `undefined procedure` error, because it is being directed to prove a before a has been entered into the database.

```
:- a.
a :- \+ a.
```

When we have a directive like `:- read(A), savMoney(A).`, it's not saying "read the value of user input into A and then set saveMoney to A". Instead, it's saying something more like, "if this program is loaded, then A is a value read in from user input *and* A is savMoney." Suppose you run the program and enter 100 at the first prompt (the plain prompt is `|`). What happens?

1. prolog unifies the variable A with 100.
2. prolog tries to prove savMoney(100).
3. it replies `Warning: Goal (directive) failed: user:(read(_G2072),savMoney(_G2072))`.

This is because, while savMoney(30000) is true, savMoney(100) is not. A directive does not assert the contents of its body, it only tells prolog  to prove those contents.

What you are trying to do is allow the user to *assert* a previously unknown fact into the database. As indicated by mbratch, this requires using the predicate `assertz/1`<sup>2</sup>. However, predicted that be changed during run-time are differentiated from standard predicates.

If you try to define a reestablished predicate in a program, you'll get an error. E.g., consult a file consisting of the following declaration:

```
length(2, y).
```

You'll receive an error:

```
ERROR: /Users/aporiac/myprolog/swi/studies/test.pl:18:
No permission to modify static procedure `length/2'
Defined at /opt/local/lib/swipl-6.2.6/boot/init.pl:2708
```

This tells us that 'length/2' is *static* and that it is already defined in init.pl file at line 2708.

The same happens if you try to assert a static predicate with `assertz/1`. You can try this by querying `assertz(savMoney(100))` in swipl. In order to add new facts or rules about a predicate, we have to declare the predicate to be *dynamic*.

This is accomplished with [`dynamic/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28dynamic%29/1). To assure that prolog knows which of our predicates are to be counted as dynamic, we give it a directive like so<sup>3</sup>:

```
:- dynamic savMoney/1.
```

If you've added that to your file (*before* you define the predicate), you can then query `?- assertz(savMoney(100)).` to add the new fact to the database. Now, if you query `?- savMoney(X)`, you'll get

```
X = 30000;
X = 100.
```

There are now two possible values for X, because we've added another fact to the database.

Of course, in your case, you don't want to keep adding values to `savMoney/1`, you want to be able to update and replace the value.

That calls for `retract/1` (If you think there's a chance that more than one occurrence the asserted predicate could get added at some point, then you can use `retractall/1` to clear all instances). Now we can write a rule like the following:

```
set_saved(Amount) :-
    retract( savMoney(_) ),
    assertz( savMoney(Amount) ).
```

`set_saved(Amount)` is true if `savMoney(_)` can be retracted and removed from the database and the new fact `savMoney(Amount)` can be asserted.

I've just seen that CapelliC has provided a simple input interface, and a much more concise solution to the problem, but here's my version of your example program in case it might be informative. (I didn't actually get around to adding the prompt and input, but querying, e.g., `?- set_saved(100)`, does what you'd expect).

```
:- dynamic [ savMoney/1,
             earn/1,
             depPeople/1 ].


do(save) :- save_bal(bad).
do(act) :- save_bal(good), inc(good).
do(comb) :- save_bal(good), inc(bad).
save_bal(good) :- savMoney(X), depPeople(Y), Min is Y * 1000, X >= Min.
save_bal(bad) :- not(save_bal(good)).
inc(good) :- earn(Z), depPeople(Y), MinE is 3000 + Y * 400, Z >= MinE.
inc(bad) :- not(inc(good)).

savMoney(30000).
earn(60000).
depPeople(4).

set_saved(Amount) :-
    retract( savMoney(_) ),
    assertz( savMoney(Amount) ).

set_earned(Amount) :-
    retract( earn(_) ),
    assertz( earn(Amount) ).

set_people_in_department(Number) :-
    retract( depPeople(_) ),
    assertz( depPeople(Number) ).

report([Saved, Earned, People]) :-
    Saved   = savMoney(_) , Saved,
    Earned  = earn(_)     , Earned,
    People  = depPeople(_), People.
```

---

1. `\+/1` is the standard negation operator in swi-prolog and [`not/1` is depreciated](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=not/1).
2. `assert/1` is equivalent to, and depreciated in favor of, `assertz/1`. `asserta/1` asserts the fact or clause as the first instance of the predicate at hand, while `assertz/1` asserts it as the last. (Cf. the manual section on the [Database](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=db)).
3. Of course, this goes against the interpretation of the directive I suggested before. My interpretation fits when you're using 'normal' predicates in a directive. But, most often, we see directives used for special predicates like in module declarations (`:- module(name, [<list of exported predicates>]`) or module imports (`:- use_module([<list of modules>])`).

Comment: I think your answer is very informative. Mine skipped over explaining several details, like =.., or the improper use of directives.

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid it might be too informative ;). I think it's a side effect of my awkward learning-by-teaching. In any case, the elegance and concision of your solution is very illuminating. The answer is well crafted, too, I think: just enough info to solve the problem with hints to spark curiosity for further inquiry.